# How to set the 'Angle of first slice' on a doughnut chart in Python openpyxl

Tags: python, openpyxl, xlsxwriter

How to set the 'Angle of first slice' on a doughnut chart in Python openpyxl?

For a simple doughnut chart like:

```
    chart = DoughnutChart()
    labels = Reference(WorkSheet, min_col=1, min_row=2, max_row=5)
    data = Reference(WorkSheet, min_col=1, min_row=1, max_row=5)
    chart.add_data(data, titles_from_data=True)
    chart.set_categories(labels)
```

I have a few slices like:

```
slices = [DataPoint(idx=i) for i in range(4)]
plain, jam, lime, chocolate = slices
chart.series[0].data_points = slices
plain.graphicalProperties.solidFill = "FAE1D0"
jam.graphicalProperties.solidFill = "BB2244"
lime.graphicalProperties.solidFill = "22DD22"
chocolate.graphicalProperties.noFill = True
```

How can a rotate the first slice or set the excel chart setting for "Angle of first slice". I don;t see anything like this in the openpyxl "Read the Docs".

Maybe something like:

```
chocolate.rot = "-270"
```

Can this be done with another library? (xlsxwriter)

Thanks!!

Comment: Your best approach is to do this in Excel and look at the XML of the resulting chart. You should then be able to work out what you need to do in openpyxl.

Comment: Charlie Clark: Are there any instructions on how to write the code after I compare the XML?

Comment: No, but the openpyxl API is almost 1:1 what you see in the XML.